# SwiftUI TabView with PageTabViewStyle in Landscape on device with safeArea adding odd leading edge inset

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I have a TabView with PageTabViewStyle and when my device is in landscape orientation, there is an odd inset on the leading edge.  This is not there on devices without a safeArea and it is not there on any edge in portrait.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Color.red
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be the TabView doing that. That is actually the "prior" view, which would be an empty view for your set up. You can see if you run this code in landscape:

```
var body: some View {
    TabView {
        Color.red
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        Color.green
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        Color.blue
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
    .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
```

Then swipe to the next view. You will see that slice of the screen has turned red. Swipe again and it turns blue.

The fix: set a `.frame` on the `TabView` that is the device size, but all of it in a `ScrollView` and put an `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` on that:

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        TabView {
            Color.red
            Color.green
            Color.blue
        }
        .frame(
            width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width ,
            height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        )
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
```

And yes, the `TabView` can scroll vertically, but it will spring back.

Comment: No idea why it works but it does.   Thanks so much for this. awesome solution.

Comment: I put it all in GeometryReader and used proxy for dimensions rather than using UIScreen but same result.  Thanks again.

Comment: also can get rid of the bounce issue with: ScrollView(.horizontal)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have only the background in fullscreen try it like this:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        // Background ignoring safe area
        LinearGradient(colors: [Color(hue: 0.106, saturation: 0.234, brightness: 0.922, opacity: 1.0), Color.white], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        // TabView
        TabView() {
            Onboarding1()
            Onboarding2()
            Onboarding3()
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
    }
}
```