# Vertical Paging in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, paging, tabview

I'm creating a vertical paging view via TabView following [this](https://blog.prototypr.io/how-to-vertical-paging-in-swiftui-f0e4afa739ba)

Everything is perfect except the strange right margin as highlighted in pic below.

Here is the code I use. Appreciate it if anyone could point out the root cause.

[image]

```swift
import SwiftUI

fileprivate struct VCompatibleTabView<Content: View>: View {
    let proxy: GeometryProxy
    let content: Content
    
    init(proxy: GeometryProxy, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.proxy = proxy
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            // Credit to Gary Tokmen for this bit of Geometry Reader code: https://blog.prototypr.io/how-to-vertical-paging-in-swiftui-f0e4afa739ba
            TabView {
                content
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90)) // Rotate content
                .frame(
                    width: proxy.size.width,
                    height: proxy.size.height
                )
            }
            .frame(
                width: proxy.size.height, // Height & width swap
                height: proxy.size.width
            )
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(90), anchor: .topLeading) // Rotate TabView
            .offset(x: proxy.size.width) // Offset back into screens bounds
            .tabViewStyle(
                PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never)
            )
        } else {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
                    content
                }
            }
            .frame(
                width: proxy.size.width,
                height: proxy.size.height)        }
    }
}

struct BBYouView: View {

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                VCompatibleTabView(proxy: proxy) {
                    ForEach(0..<3, id: \.self) { item in
                        Rectangle().fill(Color.pink)
                        .frame(
                            width: proxy.size.width,
                            height: proxy.size.height
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .background(Color.yellow)
    }


}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI TabView with PageTabViewStyle in Landscape on device with safeArea adding odd leading edge inset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69563644/swiftui-tabview-with-pagetabviewstyle-in-landscape-on-device-with-safearea-addin)

Comment: Hey...any update on this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### Horizontal/Vertical paging in iOS 17

From **iOS 17**, you don't need to do the hack of rotating the tab view and you can enable the paging behavior by applying the following modifier on the `ScrollView`:

```
.scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
```

So anything inside the `ScrollView` like a simple `ForEach` inside a stack would be paging as desired. This works for both `horizontal` and `vertical` scrollviews.

Answer (score 2):

There is iOS17 modifier `.scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)`, for older versions this hack should work:

```
import SwiftUIIntrospect

GeometryReader { proxy in
    ScrollView {
        LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach([Color.red, Color.green, Color.blue], id: \.self) { color in
                color.frame(proxy.size)
            }
        }
    }
    .introspect(.scrollView, on: .iOS(.v15, .v16, .v17)) { sv in
        sv.isPagingEnabled = true
    }
}
```